# Input type checkbox checked:before styling not rendering in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I'm having issue with :checked styling for my custom checkbox in Internet explorer. It works fine in chrome ,friefox and safari.

[image]

How look in IE..

[image]

```
<div class="field">
<input autocomplete="off" id="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
<label class="title-checkbox">Accept terms & conditions.</label>
</div>

    .field input[type="checkbox"] {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: solid 1px rgba(97, 80, 77, 0.5);
        float: left;
        outline: 0;
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        position: relative;
        padding: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
       }
    .field input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        background: #ed8b00;
        left: 3px;
        }
```

Can anyone help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of IE is it?

Comment: IE version 11..

Comment: you should post the code for your actually input too

Comment: Are you sur you haven't any issues in chrome, safari, firefox ? because :before and :after elements on input shouldn't work...

Comment: why re-posting the same question that got closed ? simply check the duplication and you will get the answer

Comment: @AlexVand it's working fine in chrome, firefox and safari no issue.

Comment: yes, please, add html part too, cause it's really strange that pseudo-elements working with <input>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263152/internet-explorer-inputcheckedbefore-styling-is-not-rendering

Comment: @NatDavydova some browser like chrome support pseudo element on input tag ... but we should not use them as they sould not work

Answer (score 1):

:after and :before not meant to be used on replaced elements such as form elements (inputs). that's why it doesn't work on IE

Generally you use the label element to make before element on input checkbox like this :

```css
.field input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px rgba(97, 80, 77, 0.5);
    float: left;
    outline: 0;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   
   .field input[type="checkbox"] +label{
     position: relative;
   }
   
.field input[type="checkbox"]:checked +label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    background: #ed8b00;
    left: -20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test"  value="ok">
  <label for="test">I'a a label</label>
</div>
```

you can also use image of your checkbox in label before and completely hide input if you want your own style.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code it will work fine on all browser (IE 10+, Chrome, Mozilla and Safari)

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label></label>
</div>

.checkbox{
  position:relative;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:0;
}
.checkbox label:before{
  content:"";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before{
  background:#000000;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYjgvR#anon-login)